# How to dynamically import only the JS from a component and still split its assets?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, sass, dynamic-import

I have got a component which is being imported dynamically, by an entry script file:

```js
let button: HTMLButtonElement;

button = document.querySelector("#myButton") as HTMLButtonElement;

button.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  
  const { 
    default: Greeter 
  } = await import(
    /* webpackChunkName: "greeter" */ 
    '../shared/greeter/greeter'
  );

  new Greeter('Hello, govner!');
});
```

When the user clicks a button, all the component scripts and styles are loaded.

While this works, it's not good becase **I need the component styles to be rendered statically**, so the page style is not broken, until the user clicks the button.

The solution would be importing the component styles, along with this entry script file:

```js
import './index.scss';
import './greeter.scss';
```

**What it produces:**

- component styles are loaded statically, along with the rest of the page;
- when/if they hit the button, then they'll have a component with behaviors.

Although, it compiles both stylesheets into only one file: `index.[contentHash].css`.

Not good! Reasons being:

- file size;
- not possible to achieve *cache busting*, properly.

**What I expect:**

- split stylesheets;
- automatically inject component corresponding stylesheet, into HTML;
- dynamically load component script.

This would make it possible to:

- have smaller files;
- do *cache busting* only on updated style chunks.

Comment: dynamic import the styles using await before the greeter on button click? Takes 2 sequential requests still, but forces the css to go first.

Comment: Alternatively, in webpack configure the `greeter.scss` file to be inlined as javascript instead of a separate file.

Comment: I can't import sass files, dynamically. VSCode throws ts(2307).

Comment: inline code would not cache.

Comment: it will be cacheable along with the `greeter` js bundle if you do it inline. If not, you can make a js file that imports the sass file, then import that js file dynamically (rather than dynamically importing the sass file)